# Wrapping each script with classes causes errors

Tags: unity, javascript

The goal here is to change variables from another script. Thing is that they must be in classes, so for example I wrapped this code (which is from **PadControl.js**):

```
#pragma strict

public var ball : GameObject;
public var moveSpeed : float = 10;
public var rotationSpeed : float = 10;

function Update () {
    var padMove : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var padRotate : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    this.transform.position.x += padMove * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    this.transform.rotation.y += padRotate * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}

function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision){
    if(col.gameObject.name == "Ball"){
//      Debug.Log("SAY SOMETHING");
    }
}
```

like so:

```
#pragma strict

public class PadControl{
    public var ball : GameObject;
    public var moveSpeed : float = 10;
    public var rotationSpeed : float = 10;

    function Update () {
        var padMove : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var padRotate : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        this.transform.position.x += padMove * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        this.transform.rotation.y += padRotate * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision){
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Ball"){
    //      Debug.Log("SAY SOMETHING");
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in this tutorial coming from Unity's website (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/statics)

But when I do it, this is the error:

> Assets/PadControl.js(12,22): BCE0019: 'transform' is not a member of 'PadControl'.
>   Assets/PadControl.js(13,22): BCE0019: 'transform' is not a member of 'PadControl'.

And I really don't know what's actually going on and what should I do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the start of your class to this:

```
public class PadControl extends MonoBehaviour {
```

Without adding `MonoBehaviour`, the class is just a class that isn't seen as a Component, and doesn't inherit `transform`, `gameObject`, etc.

Comment: It's strange that Unity tutorials didn't do it with the `extends MonoBehaviour` in the JavaScript demos.

Comment: If you don't define a class within your JS file, a class with the name of your JS file (excluding the .js extension) is created as an extended MonoBehaviour for you automatically (it's like it invisibly wraps around your code for you). But yes, some of the Unity docs examples aren't the best.